CMake - Unable to link properly against abseil on MacOS
I have build and installed abseil from source like this:
cd ./abseil-cpp
git checkout 5dd240724366295970c613ed23d0092bcf392f18
mkdir build
cd ./build
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ..
make -j 4
sudo make install

This is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fPIC")
set(OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE LEGACY)
option(WITH_PROTOBUF PROTOBUF_DIR)

if(WITH_PROTOBUF)
    set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR ${WITH_PROTOBUF}/include)
    set(PROTOBUF_LIB_DIR ${WITH_PROTOBUF}/lib)
endif()

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(gRPC REQUIRED)
find_package(absl REQUIRED)

if(APPLE)
    set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0")
    set(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0/include")
    set(OPENSSL_LIBRARIES "/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3.0/lib")
endif ()

find_package (OpenSSL REQUIRED)
# set macro-directory
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/macros)

if(absl_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Abseil found:")
    if(absl::base_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "  - absl::base found")
    endif()
    if(absl::synchronization_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "  - absl::synchronization found")
    endif()
    if(absl::strings_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "  - absl::strings found")
    endif()
    if(absl::memory_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "  - absl::memory found")
    endif()
    if(absl::time_FOUND)
        message(STATUS "  - absl::time found")
    endif()
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Abseil not found!")
endif()


file(GLOB_RECURSE Source_Files
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Configuration/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Crypto/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Database/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/DataSchemas/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Dynamic/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Component/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Component/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Profiler/*.h
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Profiler/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Signal/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Http/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Memory/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Logging/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Logging/*.cxx
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Networking/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Server/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Threading/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Utils/*.cpp
)

add_library(Vibranium-Engine SHARED ${Source_Files})

target_include_directories(Vibranium-Engine PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/stb
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/rapidjson/include
        ${PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR}
        ${absl_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

if(APPLE)
    include_directories(/opt/homebrew/include)
    include_directories(/usr/local/include)
    target_link_options(Vibranium-Engine PRIVATE -Wl,-ld_classic)
endif()

target_link_libraries(Vibranium-Engine PUBLIC
        boost
        curl
        fmt
        ImGui
        ImGuizmo
        mysql
        utf8cpp
        tabulate::tabulate
        gtest_main
        sentry::sentry
        b_stacktrace::b_stacktrace
        xmem
        ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        DebugUtils
        Detour
        DetourCrowd
        DetourTileCache
        Recast
        OpenSSL::SSL
        OpenSSL::Crypto
        ${Protobuf_LIBRARIES}
        ${MYSQL_LIBRARIES}
        absl::base
        absl::synchronization
        absl::strings
        absl::memory
        absl::time
        gRPC::grpc++
        gRPC::grpc++_reflection
)

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tests)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Vibranium)

if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources)
    message(STATUS "New ${AppName} Engine Resources folder will be created in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources/")
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Resources DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine)
else()
    file(GLOB Resources ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Engine/Resources/*)
    file(COPY ${Resources} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/Engine/Resources)
endif()

if(APPLE)
    if (NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib/SDL2.framework)
        file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/SDL2/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib)
    else()
        file(GLOB SDL2_LIBRARY_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dep/SDL2/*)
        file(COPY ${SDL2_LIBRARY_FILES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib/)
    endif()
endif()

set_target_properties(
        Vibranium-Engine
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib
)

install(TARGETS Vibranium-Engine LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
set_target_properties(RecastDemo PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)

At 100 build, at linking stage I get this error:
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a'
ld: Undefined symbols:
  absl::lts_20211102::CHexEscape(absl::lts_20211102::string_view), referenced from:
      void absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::InvokeObject<grpc_core::StatusToString(absl::lts_20211102::Status const&)::$_0, void, absl::lts_20211102::string_view, absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>(absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::VoidPtr, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::string_view>::type, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>::type) in libgpr.a[42](status_helper.cc.o)
      void absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::InvokeObject<grpc_core::StatusToString(absl::lts_20211102::Status const&)::$_0, void, absl::lts_20211102::string_view, absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>(absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::VoidPtr, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::string_view>::type, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>::type) in libgpr.a[42](status_helper.cc.o)
      void absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::InvokeObject<grpc_core::StatusToString(absl::lts_20211102::Status const&)::$_0, void, absl::lts_20211102::string_view, absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>(absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::VoidPtr, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::string_view>::type, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>::type) in libgpr.a[42](status_helper.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::FormatTime(absl::lts_20211102::string_view, absl::lts_20211102::Time, absl::lts_20211102::TimeZone), referenced from:
      grpc_core::AwsRequestSigner::AwsRequestSigner(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>>>, grpc_error**) in libgrpc.a[551](aws_request_signer.cc.o)
      grpc_core::AwsRequestSigner::GetSignedRequestHeaders() in libgrpc.a[551](aws_request_signer.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::FormatTime(absl::lts_20211102::Time), referenced from:
      grpc_service_account_jwt_access_credentials::debug_string() in libgrpc.a[561](jwt_credentials.cc.o)
      void absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::InvokeObject<grpc_core::StatusToString(absl::lts_20211102::Status const&)::$_0, void, absl::lts_20211102::string_view, absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>(absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::VoidPtr, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::string_view>::type, absl::lts_20211102::functional_internal::ForwardT<absl::lts_20211102::Cord const&>::type) in libgpr.a[42](status_helper.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::ToTimespec(absl::lts_20211102::Time), referenced from:
      grpc_core::ToGprTimeSpec(absl::lts_20211102::Time) in libgpr.a[45](time_util.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::Base64Escape(absl::lts_20211102::string_view), referenced from:
      grpc_core::channelz::SocketNode::Security::Tls::RenderJson() in libgrpc.a[404](channelz.cc.o)
      grpc_core::channelz::SocketNode::Security::Tls::RenderJson() in libgrpc.a[404](channelz.cc.o)
      grpc_core::channelz::(anonymous namespace)::PopulateSocketAddressJson(std::__1::map<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>, grpc_core::Json, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const, grpc_core::Json>>>*, char const*, char const*) in libgrpc.a[404](channelz.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::Notification::Notify(), referenced from:
      grpc_core::Server::ShutdownUnrefOnRequest() in libgrpc.a[618](server.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::Notification::~Notification(), referenced from:
      grpc_core::Server::~Server() in libgrpc.a[618](server.cc.o)
      grpc_core::Server::ShutdownAndNotify(grpc_completion_queue*, void*) in libgrpc.a[618](server.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::RFC3339_full, referenced from:
      grpc_core::ExternalAccountCredentials::OnImpersenateServiceAccountInternal(grpc_error*) in libgrpc.a[552](external_account_credentials.cc.o)
  absl::lts_20211102::UnknownError(absl::lts_20211102::string_view), referenced from:
      grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver::ZoneQuery::OnDone(grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver*, grpc_http_response const*, grpc_error*) in libgrpc.a[49](google_c2p_resolver.cc.o)
      grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver::ZoneQuery::OnDone(grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver*, grpc_http_response const*, grpc_error*) in libgrpc.a[49](google_c2p_resolver.cc.o)
      grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver::ZoneQuery::OnDone(grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::GoogleCloud2ProdResolver*, grpc_http_response const*, grpc_error*) in libgrpc.a[49](google_c2p_resolver.cc.o)

Any idea why and how can I fix it so it links properly again abseil ?

Symbols from grpc_core:: namespace are from gRPC++ library. For satisfy reference from those symbols to absl ones you need to link with absl **after** gRPC++. But the target_link_libraries` call demonstrates the opposite order.

Tried that and no difference.

You may ask make to print exact command line being executed (with VERBOSE=1 option) and inspect failed command line for the linker. Check that in the given command line the library libgpr.a (consumer of those symbols) comes before absl libraries (provider of those symbols). You may also check whether some of absl library (referenced in that command line) actually defines those symbols.

This is most likely caused by inconsistent compiler options used when building gRPC and Abseil. I'd suggest using the same CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD across all libraries involved and your application. Note that Abseil can switch between std::string_view and absl::string_view depending on options, which can cause this kind of issue when mixing those up.
